# Bootstrap 3. stop nav-pills from overlaping thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I have been trying for hours to create a div with an image(thumbnail) and then some nav pills under it. But they always overlap the image. I have tried everything. This is the HTML and the CSS, I use bootstrap 3:

```
<div class = "col-md-4">
<div class = "row clearfix div_image">
    <img src="..." class= "img-thumbnail"/>
</div>

<div class = "div_pills row clearfix">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li>
       Text <span class="badge"> Number2 </span> 
   </li>
   <br>
    <li>
       Text2 <span class="badge">Number</span> 
    </li>
     <br>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

 css:

.div_image{
max-height: 230px;
max-width: 230px;
display: block;
 }
.div_pills{
 display:block
 }
```

This is the result. Pills overlaping thumbnail:
[Pills over Thumbnail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCT55Sfg_YzcXV3WV9vckhWRHc/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like the Pills under the Thumbnail not over it. I am declaring "rows" and "display:block".. why do they overlap?.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  As a side note, you don't need `clearfix` if you use `row` because `row` already has the clearfix fix.  Also, when you use `row` you get negative margins.  If you're not using any columns then you don't need a row.  http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/U8HH2/4/

Comment: This is weird. I added a little more information that might be important: the `<div class = "col-md-4">` that wraps everything. Because the image is larger than 230px, I decided to change the css to `max-height:230px`. Anyway, it doesn't work, the pills overlap the thumbnail. More explicitly, as I increase the thumbnail's div max-height, it becomes overlapped by the pills, the pills don't get pushed down, they don't move.

Comment: There is probably other CSS effecting this which you aren't showing. Try to reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: @alejoss still can't reproduce I'm afraid. http://jsfiddle.net/U8HH2/7/

Comment: Guys thanks for trying. I have checked many times now. The code is the same, it is all inside a `col-md-4` and when I increase the size of the div, the navs don't move down. Are you using bootstrap3? Anyway it doesn't matter anymore, I decided I give up on increasing the size of the image, 160px is fine for a profile pic.